# Dynamic data in Cucumber tables

Tags: cucumber, bdd

I have a [Cucumber](http://cukes.info/) table, one of the fields is a date which I would like to have populated with todays date.
Is there a way of doing this without having to hard code todays date into the table?

Basically I would like to enter `Time.now.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")` into the table and not have it break.

Comment: Note: yes, I know how to click on a tag. I am playing dumb to show the importance of: proper capitalization, providing context in a question, correct tagging...

Comment: A quick search with Google suggests that BDD and Cucumber are related to Ruby on Rails - which might be transparently obvious if you move in those circles but not if you don't.

Comment: Cucumber is actually related to ruby, not RoR. Non rails developers use it to test their code. I use it to test Java code. And BDD is not related to Rails, it is Behavioral Driven Development, a different style than TDD, Test Driven Development.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Since the table is being processed by your step definition, you could put a special place holder in the table, such as the string "TODAYS_DATE", and then use `map_column!` to process the data in the column to the format you want.

For example given the following table

```
Given the following user records
  | username | date        |
  | alice    | 2001-01-01  |
  | bob      | TODAYS_DATE |
```

In your step definition you would have

```
Given /^the following user records$/ do |table|
  table.map_column!('date') do |date| 
    if date == 'TODAYS_DATE'
      date = Time.now.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
    end
    date
  end
  table.hashes.each do |hash|
    #Whatever you need to do
  end
end
```

Note this only changes the values when you ask for the hash. table and table.raw will remain the same, but whenever you need the row hashes, they will be converted by the code within the map_column!

Comment: can we see this in Java?

Answer (score 8):

I know it's been ages since this question was asked but I was doing something similar with Cucumber recently so here's an alternative solution if anyone's interested...

```
Given the following user records
 | username | date                             |
 | bob      | Time.now.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")    |
```

And then in your step definition just eval() the date string

```
Given /^the following user records$/ do |table|
  table.hashes.each do |hash|
    date = eval(hash["date"])
  end
end
```

Though unlike Brandon's example this wont let you put in exact dates as well without some further logic.

Comment: shouldn't it be hash["date"] = eval(hash["date"]) ? it worked that way for me

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't work for the case given by the OP which contains an entry '2001-01-01' -- this evals to 1999 as it's just simple integer arithmetic. You'd have to put something like 
   Date.parse('2001-01-01')
in your table to get the general result.

Answer (score 3):

bodnarbm's answer is pretty good if that is what you want to do.  My own suggestion would be to take a look at the [timecop gem](http://blog.smartlogicsolutions.com/2008/11/19/timecop-freeze-time-in-ruby-for-better-testing/).  Use it to set time to a known day then adjust your tables accordingly.

Comment: Cool gem, I definitely can think of some uses for it in my current code projects.

Answer (score 0):

Based on fixtures files I created this code:

**Feature:**

```
Given the following "Inquirers":
  | id | email                    | start_date        |
  |  1 | alberto@deco.proteste.pt | <%= Time.now %>   |
```

**Helper:**

```
Given(/^the following "(.*?)":$/) do |model, table|
  table.hashes.each do |hash|
    attributes = Rack::Utils.parse_nested_query(hash.to_query)
    object     = model_name.classify.constantize.new

    attributes.keys.each do |key|
      object.send("#{key}=", ERB.new(value).result())
    end
    ...
  end
end
```